# why my javascript its use to long time to run?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm working with Cloud Functions for Firebase, and I get a timeout with some of my functions. I'm pretty new with JavaScript. It looks like I need to put a `for` inside a promise, and I get some problems. The code actually get off from for too early, and I think he make this in a long time. Do you have some way to improve this code and make the code faster?

```
exports.firebaseFunctions = functions.database.ref("mess/{pushId}").onUpdate(event => {
    //first i get event val and a object inside a firebase
    const original = event.data.val();
    const users = original.uids; // THIS ITS ALL USERS UIDS!!

    // so fist i get all users uids and put inside a array
    let usersUids = [];
    for (let key in users) {
        usersUids.push(users[key]);
    }

    // so now i gonna make a promise for use all this uids and get token's device 
    //and save them inside a another child in firebase!!
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
            let userTokens = [];
            usersUids.forEach(element => {
                admin.database().ref('users/' + element).child('token').once('value', snapShot => {
                    if (snapShot.val()) { // if token exist put him inside a array
                        userTokens.push(snapShot.val());
                    }
                })
            })
            resolve({
                userTokens
            })
        }) // now i make then here, from get userTokens and save in another child inside a firebase database
        .then((res) => {
            return admin.database().ref("USERS/TOKENS").push({
                userTokens: res,
            })
        })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making network requests with firebase, so maybe that's why it's slow. You are making one request per user, so if you have 100 ids there, it might as well take a while.

But there's another problem that I notice, that is: you are just resolving to an empty list. To wait for several promises, create an array of promises, and then use `Promise.all` to create a promise that waits for all of them in parallel.

When you call resolve, you have already done the forEach, and you have started every promise, but they have not been added to the list yet. To make it better, chance it to a `map` and collect all the returned promises, and then return `Promise.all`.

Comment: hm, thank you, can u have give some example from this `Promise.all´ , i think understand, but english its not my native league, so if u show me something maybe can help more, but if u cant send, thanks from the same way, u give me a light from this problem !!!

Comment: I'm not an expert on this firebase lib you are using, but assuming it uses promises, something like this: `return Promise.all(usersUids.map(id => admin.database().ref('users/' + id).child('token').once('value')))`, that's a promise that waits for all requests and then resolves to a list of results.